# Bootstrap make a parent for col's

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a parent div between a row and the containing col's like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="rowcontent">
        <div class="col-md-6">afafafaf</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">afaf</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason for this is that i want to add a background to the row's, if i add the background  to

```
  <div class="row">
```

the background is placed over the margins. But when i do it like the example code the background isn't visible because the height of rowcontent is 0. How can i change it that the height of rowcontent will be the same height as the col's.

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/gXtpjMLOPs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the class `clearfix` (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix):

```
<div id="rowcontent" class="clearfix">
```

It's a fix for issues with the block formatting context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

Comment: Nice i thought clearfix was to remove space (as in height) betweeen stacked col''s,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table` and `table-cell` to get your parent to match its children's dimensions.

```
#rowcontent
  {
     display: table;
     background: red;
   }

#rowcontent > div 
   {
     display: table-cell; 
     width:50%;
   }
```

[BootPly demo](http://www.bootply.com/1O2aNJI1gp)